# Get the Selected ListBox item MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I've simply done the following:

```
public string  X
{
    get { return _X; }
    set
    {
        _X= value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("X");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding X}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolToggleListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 12 8 12" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock Text="TEXT1"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock Text="TEXT2"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock Text="TEXT3"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Instead of getting the item only, I'm getting the following:

> System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: SELECTED_ITEM_HERE

Comment: Looks to me like you may be putting listboxitems in the listbox rather than binding a collection of strings to it's itemssource.

Comment: It's the case indeed. If I create I ever do the binding instead of writing them down in XAML, would that fix the issue?

Comment: I can't see all the rest of your code.  I think you can put a bunch of strings directly in a lisbox if you reference mscorlib but I suggest you get used to binding. Everything.

Comment: they're basically textblocks. I included the complete code.

Comment: Well yes, you're just going to get a listboxitem with a textblock trying to "fit" into a string and bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the the textblock and set `_x` the text

```
private string _X;
public object X
{
    get { return _X; }
    set
     {
        var a = ((ListBoxItem)value).Content as TextBlock;
        _X = a.Text;
       NotifyOfPropertyChange("X");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead specifying listview items directly in xaml, you can bind those values to itemssource.

i have tried following code snippet

```
  public Class1()
        {
            TextList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "TEXT1", "TEXT2" };
        }
        private string _X;
        public string X
        {
            get { return _X; }
            set
            {
                _X = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> TextList { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

in xaml,

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding X}" ItemsSource="{Binding TextList}"/>
```

with this i am getting only "TEXT2"/"TEXT1" instead with control type .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `ListBoxItems` to the `ListBox`, you should add `strings` to it:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding X}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0 10 0 0"
         xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolToggleListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 12 8 12" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <s:String>TEXT1</s:String>
    <s:String>TEXT2</s:String>
    <s:String>TEXT3</s:String>
</ListBox>
```

The other option would be to change the type of your source property to `ListBoxItem` but that's not what you want. The type of the item and the source property of the property that you are binding to `SelectedItem` must match.

Comment: @Abdou: Did you try this or what happened?